# How to convert numbers sting in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a numbers string, i.e `123956` and i would like to convert it in a list, i.e. `[1,2,3,9,5,6]`?

Comment: If it is a string, use `list("123956")` (replacing 123956 with any number string).

Comment: Thanks, for me this works fine:   a = [int(x) for x in value]